# Where did Ant-Man go at the end of the movie?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, ant-man, ant-man-2015

Towards the end of the movie, Ant-Man is shown fighting Yellowjacket.

> He begins shrinking to go between the molecules and destroy Yellowjacket's suit and starts shrinking uncontrollably. Once he stops he is shown floating around some metallic looking stuff and a couple times before this we see some other possibly high tech looking material/things.

Is there any significance to this place?  Is it shown in the comics at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR: I haven't seen it yet, but from your description it seems to be a nod to the Microverse.**

A long-established icon of the Marvel universe is [The Microverse](http://marvel.wikia.com/Microverse), a dimension of space which can only be reached by shrinking smaller than the atoms of our reality. The Microverse first appeared waaaaaaay back in 1943, specifically in [Captain America #26](http://marvel.wikia.com/Captain_America_Comics_Vol_1_26). The realm is most often associated with [The Fantastic Four](http://marvel.wikia.com/Fantastic_Four_(Earth-616)) and, of course, [Ant-Man](http://marvel.wikia.com/Scott_Lang).

[image]

Comment: and yeah, it's *hugely* important to the movie, since they practically beat you over the head with a sledgehammer that has "[spoiler] is still alive in there!" written on it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I knew that person was going to be revealed to be alive with the way they were building it up. I didn't know that it would be in a different place though. Thanks.

Comment: I assume we're talking about a certain winged female.

Answer (score 0):

In the movie, it is described as going "subatomic."  Basically, he becomes smaller and smaller and his perception of reality changes due to this.

From the [transcript](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Ant-Man):

> You would go subatomic.
>
> What does that mean?
>
> It means that you would enter a quantum realm.
>
> What does that mean?
>
> It means that you would enter a reality where all concepts of time and space become irrelevant as you shrink for all eternity.

The scene in question:

> **Scott Lang**: I’m gonna have to shrink between the molecules to get in there. [to Cross] Get away from us! Daddy, help! [Scott jumps up to head towards Cross’ particle pack] I love you, Cassie. [Scott shrinks to a small enough size to break into Cross’ particle pack, this causes Cross to go subatomic and disappear]